# Method of Characteristics Boundary Condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

So this is a pretty simple question that I just need a bit of clarification on where I am messing up:

$$\frac{∂w}{∂t} + 4 \frac{∂w}{∂x} = 0,~~~  w(0,t) = \sin(3t)$$

My method so far:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = 4$$

$$x = 4t + x_0$$

$$x_0 = x-4t$$

This is where my problem comes up. Whats the next step? Usually with an initial condition I would simply substitute it into the condition, but how do I proceed from here?

Comment: What your calculations show is that the function $w(x,t)$ is constant along any curve on the form $x - 4t = $ constant. This means that $w(x,t) = f(x-4t)$ for some (differentiable) function $f$. Now impose the initial condition by taking $x=0$. This will give you the function $f$.

Comment: Thank you for your response! So the way I proceed would be f(x-4t) = w(x,t). And as such sin 3t = f(-4t). But from here is where I get confused. Where do I proceed now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a variable change to see the form $f$ has for the solution with the given initial conditions.

We know that $w(x,t)=f(x-4t)$, with $f$ some single argument, differentiable function, and $w(0,t)=\sin(3t)$, so,

$f(-4t)=\sin(3t)$, as you correctly saw.

Defining $u=-4t$, we have $t=-\dfrac{u}{4}$ and $3t=-\dfrac{3u}{4}$. From here we can know the form the formula for $f$ has to have: $f(u)=\sin\left(-\dfrac{3u}{4}\right)$. Finally,

$w(x,t)=\sin\left(-\dfrac{3}{4}(x-4t)\right)$